# MySQL error 1064 (v 5.0.96) GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql

I'm used to running on an Oracle database, so I'm not really quite sure how to trouble shoot this problem.  I've narrowed down a simple example of my query to the following:

```
 SELECT 0 as gm_rowID, 
'-ALL Grantmakers-' as grantmakerName 
FROM dual
GROUP BY 2
```

phpMyAdmin runs the SQL with the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY 2 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

Oracle can run this query just fine.  MySQL can run the query without the `GROUP BY` clause.  Any ideas?

--Here is the entire query:

```
SELECT 
    p.grantmaker_rowid as gm_rowID, 
    gm.grantmaker_companyName as grantmakerName 
FROM grantmaker_info gm, proposal_submission p 
WHERE 0=0 
AND p.grantmaker_rowid = gm.grantmaker_rowid 
UNION 
SELECT 
    0 as gm_rowID, 
    '-ALL Grantmakers-' as grantmakerName
FROM dual 
ORDER BY 2
GROUP BY 2
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: please show the whole query.

Comment: @Chester: That still can't be the entire query, as (at a minimum) it's missing both the `GROUP BY` and `LIMIT` clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Columns selected for output can be referred to in ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses using column 
>   names, column aliases, or column positions. Column positions are
>   integers and begin with 1

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Unless you only have 1 column in that table, it should run fine. My suggestion however would be to reference the column name (or alias) of whatever you're trying to `GROUP BY`.

edit: My only other suggestion is to include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for that table.

edit2: Ok I see you've updated your question.  Why not instead of `ORDER BY 2`, you `ORDER BY grantmakerName` (if that's the column you want to order by?)

Comment: By `SHOW CREATE TABLE` do you mean the column names for the table?  The query itself is just a literal query based on the `DUAL` table.  That shouldn't matter, correct?

Comment: Basically running `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the tables referenced in your query, such as: grantmaker_info, proposal_submission, and dual.  Other than providing additional details on your question, it allows us to use SQL Fiddle to help with the solution (http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Here is files for the `SHOW CREATE TABLE grantmaker_info` [https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6212377/grantmaker_info.sql](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6212377/grantmaker_info.sql) and `SHOW CREATE TABLE proposal_submission` [https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6212377/proposal_submission.sql](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6212377/proposal_submission.sql).  Dual is a system table.

Comment: Ok have a look at this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45c16/4 look at the query to the right, see if that makes sense to you.

Comment: Cool! Putting that second query in parenthesis seems to have done the trick. I wonder if this is something peculiar within MySQL or is this just general practice for and SQL queries. Thanks for your help!